# I need to send an action and a variable to the url

Tags: php, url, action

This is the action in my form

```
action="/Classes/Controllers/DoctorController.php?action=editVC"
```

the action I am sending is `?action=editVC`

I need to also send a variable I got from this block of code

```
<?php
            if(isset($_GET['userID'])){
                  $currentUserID = $_GET['userID'];
            }
        ?>
```

Given that they are all in the same file, and I want to send the variable $surrentUserID like this `?userID=$currentUserID` in the url as well along with the action.

I have tried this way but it did not work

```
action="/Classes/Controllers/DoctorController.php?action=editVC&userID=$currentUserID"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to invoke PHP and `print` the variable, so either in your HTML:

```
<form action="/Classes/Controllers/DoctorController.php?action=editVC&userID=<?php print $currentUserId; ?>">
```

Or you might prefer to concatenate the action in a string first like:

PHP:

```
<?php
$action = '/controllers/DoctorController.php?action=editVC&userID='.$currentUserId';
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="<?php print $action; ?>">...</form>
```